# How to add Material Design preset to Vite Vuetify project?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vite

I am trying to put together a quick prototype of an app using `yarn create vite --template vue-ts` Then I added `vuetify` with `yarn add vuetify@^3.1.13`.

I cannot find a way to use `vuetify-preset-*` as `vue add` is not available in a vite vue-js project. I have tried to `yarn add vue-cli-plugin-vuetify-preset-rally` directly. Then I get the **no typescript definitions** error.

Is there a practical way to be able to use this preset?

Note: `rally` is the name of a material design preset. I am using `typescript`.

Comment: all the presets were designed for vuetify 2 projects.  vuetify 3 is a complete rewrite of the framework.  the presets from v2 simply won't be compatible.

Comment: @yoduh Does it say anywhere in the documentation? Asking because, I have to present a working reasoning behind not using it.

Comment: the v2 documentation page for [presets](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/features/presets/) has been purposefully removed from [v3 documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/presets/) which is a pretty strong indicator that they're not supported.  Though they did add a new feature called [blueprints](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/blueprints/) which is very similar concept though not exactly the same.